# Why length of unit vector is greater than 1?

Tags: vectors

Length of unit vector is 1 and we get unit vector by dividing the vector with its length.

Say our vector is (3, 4).
Its length is 5.
When i normalize it i get (0.6, 0.98)

Now that should be of length 1, but its length is 1.15.

If I take Unit vector (1, 0) its length is 1.
But for most of non unit vectors, after normalizing length is greater than 1.

What did i missed?
Or i should round it to closest integer?

Edit:
I am calculating normalize values as
3/5 4/5
And length as
Sqrt(3*3 + 4*4)

Edit2:
I get it now, where dit that 0.98 came from.
Length of (3,4) was in fact greater than 5 beacause of precision of floating point in c. Turns out length of (3,4) is not equal to 5.0 by using above formula.
Really should have asked on stackoverflow.

Comment: it is $$4:5=0.8$$

Comment: How you get the "normalized" values ?

Comment: Where did the $0.98$ come from? Whatever you did to find the $0.6$ should give you $0.8$ for the second coordinate.

Comment: (1/5)(3,4) =(0.6,0.8).

Comment: But the square root of $3^2+4^2=25$ must be $5$ ! You have it already.

Comment: How did you get 4/5=0.98?

Comment: As an aside, for any nonzero vector $v$ one has $\|\frac{v}{\|v\|}\|=\frac{1}{\|v\|}\|v\|=1$, so any error in the process must be human error.  "*Or should I round it to the closest integer*" absolutely not.  You should keep it in exact terms for as long as you can which might involve keeping square roots floating around rather than giving decimal approximations.

Comment: When you normalize you "shrink" the vector to have unit lenght. This means that you are dividing the lenght $l$ of the vector by the factor $l$ itself. You have that if the vector is $(a,b)$ with lenght $l$, by the formula: $a^2+b^2=l^2$ you derive: $(\dfrac a l )^2 + (\dfrac b l)^2= \dfrac {l^2} {l^2}=1$.

Comment: This amounts to saying that you have to "shrink" by factor $l$ the two components $a$ and $b$ of the vector.

Comment: "Turns out length of $(3,4)$ is not equal to $5.0$ by using above formula.  What horrid piece of machinery did you use that could not successfully calculate $\sqrt{3^2+4^2}=\sqrt{9+16}=\sqrt{25}=5$?  That also does not explain how $\frac{3}{\sqrt{3^2+4^2}}$ was correctly calculated as $0.6$ but $\frac{4}{\sqrt{3^2+4^2}}$ was not.  I strongly recommend not relying on machinery to do calculations, especially short ones like this.  Many teachers even ban calculators on tests but in return will make sure all calculations are easily done by pen&paper.

Comment: "precision of floating point in c" It's perfectly fine to make an error, but it's important to understand the source of the error, and there's no way that floating point accuracy was the culprit here. With floating point arithmetic the norm in this case would have been accurate to like 15 digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you have made an error in your calculation. $$\sqrt{3^2 + 4^2} = 5$$ $$\frac{1}{5}*(3, 4) = (0.6, 0,8)$$ You can confirm the length of that by this: $$\sqrt{0.6^2 + 0.8^2} = 1$$